# Iterate over two arrays in pug (jade) and Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pug

I have a simple pug layout that takes an array of image source urls and an array of corresponding webpage urls, and I want to iterate over both at the same time. Essentially I want to do:

```
for ( i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
  // display photos[i]
  // display webLinks[i]
}
```

I'm trying various things in pug, like

```
block content
    h1= title

    ul
        each val, link in photos, webLinks
            a(href=link)
                img(src=val width=200 height=150)
```

But this seems to only iterate over the photos array.

I've tried other things like

```
  each val in photos
  each link in webLinks
    // rest of code
```

This gives an error saying it didn't expect a newline.

I could pass pug a single object consisting of these arrays, if that would be easier. I don't see anything in the pug iteration documentation that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pug defines the index as the second argument in an [`each` block](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html).

You can achieve what you want with accessing the value of another array in the same each block using the index of the loop itself

```
ul
    each val, index in photos
        a(href=webLinks[index])
            img(src=val width=200 height=150)
```